# Reversing "group" of strings in Python

Tags: python, string, reverse

How to reverse "groups" (not list) of strings?
For example I would like to convert "123456789" into "321654987" given that the "group" size equals to 3.

Followings are my code but it turns out to print empty strings:

```
string = "12345678901234567890"
new_string = ""
for i in range(0, len(string), 5):
    new_string = new_string + string[i:i+5:-1]
print (new_string)
```

Thanks for any input and advice.

Answer (score 2):

When using a negative step, swap the start and end values too:

```
new_string += string[i + 4:i - 1 if i else None:-1]
```

Note that the end value is excluded, and `None` should be used to include the *first* character (`-1` would slice from the end again and thus `string[4:-1:-1]` would be empty).

Demo:

```
>>> string = "12345678901234567890"
>>> new_string = ""
>>> for i in range(0, len(string), 5):
...     new_string = new_string + string[i + 4:i - 1 if i else None:-1]
... 
>>> new_string
'54321098765432109876'
```

However, it may be easier to first slice, then reverse, and save yourself the headaches of such slicings:

```
new_string += string[i:i + 4][::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple one liner for your problem would go something like.

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> testString = "123456789"
>>> group = 3
>>> "".join(chain.from_iterable([reversed(elem) for elem in zip(*[iter(testString)]*group)]))
'321654987'
```

Another Example ->

```
>>> testString = "12345678901234567890"
>>> group = 5
>>> "".join(chain.from_iterable([reversed(elem) for elem in zip(*[iter(testString)]*group)]))
'54321098765432109876'
```

Comment: It seems like unless you know you only want a specific length, the itertools method is the best.

Comment: Why? Many of these solutions can be passed the length as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in one line:

`newline = ''.join([string[i:i+n:1][::-1] for i in range(0, len(string), n)])`

Where n is the size of the "group". In your case, it would be 3. An Explanation is below:

`i in range(0, len(string), n)` is responsible for counting by three

`string[i+i+n:1]` is responsible for getting each chunk

`[::-1]` will reverse each chunk

`''.join()` joins each now-reversed chunk back into a single string.

Another option is:

`''.join([string[i+n-1:i-1 if i else None:-1] for i in range(0, len(string), n)])`

Where the selecton and reversing is done in one step.